# Is it possible to pin threads made by others that I would like to see answers for?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I stumble upon an interesting topic posted by others, I would want to be able to "follow" or "pin" the thread so I can revisit it again.

Is that possible? I keep forgetting to revisit the threads and then it gets forgotten.

Comment: Why don't you Favourite them (click the star just below the voting buttons)?